# Transitioning a GradientDrawable

Tags: android, kotlin, transitiondrawable, gradientdrawable

I have a function that creates a gradient across the background of my `MainActivity`. The gradient is created programmatically as a `GradientDrawable`. Certain interactions in the App change the color of the gradient.

The gradient and colors are properly shown, and they do change accordingly, however, I would like a transition effect on the color changes. Right now, the colors transition instantly with no crossfade.

```
fun createGradient() {
    gd.shape = GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE
    mainActivityID.background = gd
    gd.gradientType = GradientDrawable.LINEAR_GRADIENT
    gd.orientation = (GradientDrawable.Orientation.BL_TR)
}
```

Based on interactions in the App, I use a `when` statement to change the colors of the `GradientDrawable`

```
fun changeGradient(){

    //val td = gd as TransitionDrawable
    //td.isCrossFadeEnabled = true
    //td.startTransition(1500)

    when(calories){
        in 0..50 -> gd.colors = intArrayOf(
            ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.dBlue),
            ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.lBlue)
        )
        in 51..100 -> gd.colors = intArrayOf(
            ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.dRed),
            ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.lRed)
        )
        // etc...
    }
}
```

I tried casting the GradientDrawable as a TransitionDrawable (as seen in the commented code above), but that crashes with:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable cannot be cast to
>   android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable

**How do I add a 1500 millisecond transition between the GradientDrawable color changes?**

Progress crashes with `java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -16777216`

```
when(calories){
    in 0..50 -> animateGradient(gd, IntArray(Color.BLACK), IntArray(Color.CYAN))
    in 51..100 -> animateGradient(gd, IntArray(Color.RED), IntArray(Color.BLUE))
    in 101..150 -> animateGradient(gd, IntArray(Color.GREEN), IntArray(Color.YELLOW))
    // etc... about 15 more statements.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think gradient drawable has built in transition methods, but You can run your own value animator to perform color transition.

```
var anim : Animator? = null

fun animateGradient(gd: GradientDrawable, from : IntArray, to: IntArray){
    require(from.size == to.size)
    anim?.cancel()
    val arraySize = from.size
    val props = Array<PropertyValuesHolder>(arraySize){
        PropertyValuesHolder.ofObject(it.toString(), ArgbEvaluator(), from[it], to[it])
    }
    val anim = ValueAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(*props)
    anim.addUpdateListener {
        gd.colors = IntArray(arraySize){i ->
            it.getAnimatedValue(i.toString()) as Int
        }
    }
    anim.duration = 1500
    anim.start()
    this.anim = anim
}
```

**Edit**: modified method so it that tracks current color itself, reduced number of arguments.

```
var anim : Animator? = null
// variable that tracks current color - must be initialized with default gradient colors
var currentGradient = intArrayOf(
        ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.dBlue),
        ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.lBlue)
    )

fun animateGradient(targetColors: IntArray){
    val from = currentGradient
    require(from.size == targetColors.size)
    anim?.cancel()
    val arraySize = from.size
    val props = Array<PropertyValuesHolder>(arraySize){
        PropertyValuesHolder.ofObject(it.toString(), ArgbEvaluator(), from[it], targetColors[it])
    }
    val anim = ValueAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(*props)
    anim.addUpdateListener {valueAnim ->
        IntArray(arraySize){i ->
            valueAnim.getAnimatedValue(i.toString()) as Int
        }.let{
            currentGradient = it
            gd.colors = it
        }
    }
    anim.duration = 1500
    anim.start()
    this.anim = anim
}
```

Call site:

```
when(calories){
    in 0..50 -> animateGradient(intArrayOf(
        ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.dBlue),
        ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.lBlue)
    ))
    in 51..100 -> animateGradient(intArrayOf(
        ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.dRed),
        ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.lRed)
    ))
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: Should your animateGradient function replace what I have in the `when` statement? Or does it go after? Can you provide usage for this?

Comment: @Joe you call it from each invididual `when` case instead of `gd.setColors(..)`, this creates and runs transition animation. You will need to provide current gradient colors as `from` argument and target colors as `to`.

Comment: I edited my question to show progress. Your solution is crashing. I don't understand why there are two array parameters. Shouldn't those be single colors to handle the from (color 1 of the gradient) & to (color 2 of the gradient)?

Comment: @Joe modified the method to track current gradient color within it, this replaces `from` argument so you only need to provide new gradient colors.

Comment: After some trial and error, I got it to work! Thank you! The only thing that's not working is initializing currentGradient with the default colors. It looks like it doesn't want me using ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.dBlue), ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.lBlue). However, if I use Color.BLUE, Color.RED to initialize currentGradient, it works just fine. This issue is out of scope of my question, but do you know why it won't let me use ContextCompat ?

Comment: Nevermind my last comment. I got it working. Just needed to initialize the array in onCreate(). Thanks again for all of your help bud :)